# CKEDITOR in Joomla front end PHP files

Tags: php, ckeditor, joomla2.5

really stuck here. i need to install CKEditor into our Joomla! system. according to directions, i upload folder "ckeditor" then write a basic page to show a textarea with editor toolbar - instead, the page doesn't load, and console errors are here:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at eval (<anonymous>)
at jquery.min.js:2
at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
at text script (jquery.min.js:2)
at cD (jquery.min.js:2)
at y (jquery.min.js:2)
at d (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.send (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

System information is:
PHP Version-5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26; 
Web Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu); 
WebServer to PHP Interface - apache2handler; 
Version Joomla! 2.5.28 Stable [ Ember ] 10-December-2014 15:00 GMT;
Joomla! Platform Version-Joomla Platform 11.4.0 Stable.

I can get the same CKEditor folder and sample page to run on my personal ehosts.com server that has Joomla! installed. You can see this page work fine:

```
http://www.thecollectivedreamer.com/1/page1.php
```

I simply uploaded folder "ckeditor" then put literally just these 3 lines of code inside an html web page:

```
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">replace this div with CKEditor.</div>
<script>CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );</script>
```

and it displays fine on that site. But when i do this same thing on Joomla! on my work web site, it doesn't work. can someone help?

Comment: jquery version conflict?

Comment: make sense as per the errors; so i tried adding the latest jquery cdn to no avail, both jquery-3.2.1.min.js, and jquery-ui.min.js. tried a standalone page1.php with literally the same code that works in my other joomla! server; but in this environment no go.